# asp.net page load too many functions

Tags: c#, asp.net, rendering

I have an asp.net page which runs many functions in the page_load. Thus making the page so slowly. I want the page to be shown to the user first and then run the functions inside the page load. Is that anyway I can show the page first and then run the code inside the page_load?

Comment: You could use AJAX to call a separate method to load data, and then add it to the page after it has loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I suggest you move to `MVC` and don't use webforms which is so old.

In both ways you can split the `HTML` markup + `Javascript` code without using `webforms` controllers, Then simply using the javascript `onPageLoad event` and there fire the ajax reqeusts to the server..

If you really really want to use the controllers of `webforms` you can see the page lifecycle here: `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page_events(v=vs.110).aspx` then you can use for instance the `PreRender` event.